# Possesive Adjective Problem

Tags: possessives

Which one is true when the gender of the person is not accurate?

`The writer must state his/her own opinions in the paper`

`The writer must state its own opinions in the paper`

Answer (score 1):

Your options are:

1. to use the singular *their*

> The writer must state their opinions in the paper.

2. to repeat his/her

> The writer must state his/her opinion in the paper.

3. to write around it

> The writer's opinion must be stated in the paper.

4. Don't use **its**

unless the text has been composed by a computer, bot etc.

https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/97825/about-adjective-possessive-pronouns/97829